# Simple way to list order of referential integrity in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, referential-integrity

Is there a clean, simple, and preferably prepackaged (ready function?) way to list the order of referential integrity in a `Postgres` database, rather than trying to read the system tables to find that order manually, which is tedious and time consuming?

What I mean is, if the entity hierarchy is

> USER --> ACCOUNT --> TRANSACTION

meaning that a single user can have multiple accounts and that a single account can have multiple transactions, if I want to delete all the three tables without breaking any `foreign keys`, I would have to do it in the exact following order:

```
DELETE FROM TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM ACCOUNT;
DELETE FROM USER;
```

Now this is a very simple and obvious example. But real life databases have a lot more tables and foreign keys. If I wanted to delete every table down to 0 rows, is there a quick way to obtain the exact order of referential integrity to do it in?

Comment: Write a script to do data dictionary diving, given a table name?

Comment: i was hoping this function could be prepackaged

Comment: also, i am not familiar with the term `data dictionary diving`

Comment: There nay be cycles in the foreign keys graph (a table referencing itself or A -> B -> C -> A)

Comment: i get that @ypercubeᵀᴹ. but wouldn't that be indicative of a less-than-perfect DB design (which is a separate issue from the one at hand) ?

Comment: Yeah, I don't like FK cycles much. But it's very common (at least the self-referencing A->A. But that is usually not a problem if you have cascading deletes). It seems though that your FKs are defined with `ON DELETE RESTRICT`?

Comment: If you want to delete everything, you can use `truncate table "transaction", account, "user"`  (I would also strongly recommend to **not** use keywords as table names. `transaction` and `user` are reserved keywords)

Answer (score 2):

You can "dive" into the system tables and get all the tables that reference a specific table (and all those that reference them, etc). It will be a recursive query, not very difficult to write.

However, for the simple operation you want to to perform, there is a simple solution:
**`TRUNCATE`** with the magic option **`CASCADE`**:

```
truncate table a cascade ;
```

Tested at [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/TWNLEG44404)